# Flexbox right space on the right side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey whenever I use display: flex the right side of my row has a bit of a space. How can I fix that? You can't see it that good in jsfiddle, only if you use Firebug or whatever.

https://jsfiddle.net/4wLhc2ke/1/

I know its because of the margin, but I need the margin..

```
                <div class="input-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                <input type="text" class="tile-txt" placeholder="Box 1">
                <input type="text" class="tile-txt" placeholder="Box 2">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happens because your second (last) input element has a `margin-right` of `5px` remove it and it'll be as desired: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4wLhc2ke/3/)**

```
.tile-txt:last-child{
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

if you have more than one row you need to remove the margin from the elements which their index is even: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4wLhc2ke/5/)**

```
.tile-txt:nth-child(even){
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: thats working, thanks. but is there another way around? Its not working if I have 2 rows because its only applying to the last box of the second row.

Answer (score 1):

A more flex approach would be to use an `auto` left margin (flex items treat [auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#auto-margins) a bit differently than when used in a block formatting context).

```
.right-part {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqDK9/5/)